# Неточное соответствие шаблонному параметру шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17

```
template<template<typename> class>
void foo() {

}

template<typename, typename = int>
struct A {

};


int main() {
    foo<A>();
}
```

Почему эта программа компилируется gcc и msvc ([1](https://godbolt.org/z/4I8AfW) и [2](https://godbolt.org/z/KLSgYO)), но не компилируется clang ([3](https://godbolt.org/z/SBUvrv))? Должна ли она компилироваться в соответствии со стандартом?

Comment: а оно точно компилируется gcc? У меня что-то нет

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Смотря какой компилятор, я же привёл ссылку, как я компилирую

Comment: вы видимо не поняли: у меня `gcc` отказывается компилировать это код.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch можете дать ссылку на конфигурацию вашего компилятора на какой-нибудь онлайн платформе?

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04) 5.5.0 20171010 - это все что вам стоит знать о компиляторе

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch ну вот, а в вопросе используется 8.2

Comment: ну так а в чем тогда вопрос?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch А поддержка С++17 в gcc стала доступна где-то [начиная с 7 версии](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html)

Comment: @VTT вообще-то там написона с 5 и выше

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Это флажек `-std=c++17` добавили в 5, а большая часть фич реализовали только в 7.

Comment: Ни GCC, ни Cland до сих пор толком не поддерживают С++17 на уровне core language. Более того, согласно некоторым тестам, лидером в поддержке С++17 является пре-релиз Visual Studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Код корректен для C++17. Это новая возможность (или исправленный баг) языка.

Но в clang эта возможность сознательно по-умолчанию [отключена](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#p0522) (вольный перевод):

> Хотя это и разрешает отчёт о дефекте [языка С++], эта возможность отключена по умолчанию во всех версиях языка и может быть явно включена  флагом `-frelaxed-template-template-args` в Clang 4 и новее. Изменениям в стандарте не хватает соответствующих изменений в секции про *порядок разрешения частичных шаблонов* (*template partial ordering*), что приводит к ошибкам неоднозначности в ранее допустимом коде.

т.е. в данном случае нужно передать компилятору флаг `-frelaxed-template-template-args`.

Пример кода [ломаемого](https://godbolt.org/z/JnrUcA) данной возможностью (взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47293162/how-is-p0522r0-breaking-code)):

```
template<template<typename          > typename> void foo() {}
template<template<typename, typename> typename> void foo() {}
template<typename, typename = void> struct Bar {};

int main() {
    foo<Bar>(); // Неоднозначный вызов в C++17
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ваш пример практически точно повторяет пример из стандарта языка

http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.template#3

```
template<class T, class U = T> class B { /* ... */ };
template<template<class> class P> class X { /* ... */ };

X<B> xb;            // OK
```

Да, этот код корректен в С++17.

Это - выраженное изменение по отношению к С++14, где в аналогичном примере объявление `xb` была явно помечено как ошибочное.

Comment: Почему тогда clang - обычно самый соответствующий стандарту компилятор - ругается?

Comment: @cpp questions: Стандарт С++17 пока толком не реализован ни одним из компиляторов. Поэтому неожиданные "ругани" вполне естественны.